# Adding a WinUI/WinRT Xaml form to a standard C++ library

Tags: c++, winrt-xaml, winui-3, c++-winrt

I am developing a platform independent C++20 library (pure C++, no windows component) in VS2022, which among other things has a standardized error and message reporting subsystem.

While the whole library is a standard C++ DLL/Static lib I now want to add a single XAML form to it for standardizing the display of error information on Windows. I tried to simply add a blank WInUI form but this is missing the context setup of a regular WinUI/WinRT project (header file includes...).

The project has Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT and Microsoft.UI.Xaml packages installed.

Adding a new library project to the solution for the window could be an option but I could not see how this could be done so far. For example a WinUI/RT component library, but then again how to use it from the C++ libray. I guess that approach would just shift the problem.

I hope there is a solution to my problem.

P.S.: until now I have never used WinUI/RT in C++. All GUI programming was done using C#/WPF so far.

Comment: You should have a C++ library in one project (using dynamic DLL or static LIB linking) and WinUI3 stuff (controls like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/xaml-templated-controls-cppwinrt-winui-3) in another project (this last one possibly linking to the first one).

Comment: @SimonMourier This was one of my ideas but I don't see how to start this library pooroject. As WinUI3 component or as WuiniUI app and then change it to a library ? As a CppWinRT console app and then change type to a library ?

Comment: Choose the Windows Runtime Component (WinUI3) C++ from Visual Studio templates